# I'm struggeling with Multi-Dimension array input and output, I managed input, however printing doesn't work as planned

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm playing around to get the grip of multi dimensional arrays.
I have managed to have the array record the input from the user..
I'm trying to use 2 FOR loops to print with the idea that it should print 4 rows of 3 characters each

i know i can solve this if i manually type what to print, but for sure there is a way to have a loop do that for me...

here is the input and output code that i wrote:

```
    cout << "Enter characters" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            cin >> charArr[x][i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Printing the array now" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            cout << charArr[x][i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

i don't understand why some letters are gone and why it doesn't print in order...

Comment: How did you define `charArr`?

Comment: @Smokey Van Den Berg How this prompt "Enter 7 characters" is connected with the two loops that in total have 12 iterations?!

Comment: Row/columns indexes reversed, try: `charArr[x][i];`.=>  `charArr[i][x];` For loops like that, I prefer to use `row` as the outer loop variable, and `col` (short for column) as the inner loop variable, so that the array references will look like this: `charArr[row][col];`

Comment: @PaulT. while it is preferred to do that, it's not a real issue with the code.

Comment: @ Vlad yeah i noticed that after..

Comment: @PaulT. this does fix the sorting problem but still 2 chars are missing

Comment: @LiMuBei its char charArry[2][3];

Comment: How do you intend to store 4 * 3 items in an array with 2 * 3 elements storage? And, considering your reversed element subscript `charArr[x][i]`, you need an array `char charArr[3][4]`. Though, I still don't understand the `"Enter 7 characters"`. 4 * 3 = 12, isn't it?

Comment: Please, note: An array with N elements (e.g. `const int N = 10; char charArr[N];`) provides the elements `charArr[0]` ... `charArr[N-1]` -> the C/C++ array off-by-one pitfall. ;-)

Comment: okay i feel like an idiot now.. got it thanks guys

Comment: Swapping or not, you have to ensure that you access only array elements which were allocated before. In other words, what I wrote in the comment above. ^

Comment: That might be the reason for the idiomatic `for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)` loops. The N could be the number of elements of an array but last iteration is done for i == N-1. When i == N the loop bails out.

Comment: @Scheff thanks man I don't know why I thought it should be the other way around and having to count from 0 got me a bit confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where i is row and j is a column. for loop should come like this only.
in this order only we can store the input. 
In your case, you are swapping the orders.
Solution :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        cin >> charArr[i][j];
    }
}
cout << "Printing the array now" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        cout << charArr[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```